# Pandas: Multiply a column based on contents of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to get `Market Cap` from this column as a float

```
Company Info
Workhorse Group, Inc. (WKHS) Market Cap: $65.94M   
Xencor, Inc. (XNCR) Market Cap: $1.99B   
Zillow Group, Inc. (ZG) Market Cap: $10.28B   
Zillow Group, Inc. (Z) Market Cap: $10.17B   
Zogenix, Inc. (ZGNX) Market Cap: $1.99B
```

Desired output

```
Market Cap
65940000.00
1990000000.00
10280000000.00
10170000000.00
1990000000.00
```

I can get the number (might be a better way) with this

```
df['market_cap'] = df['Company Info'].str.split('$').str.get(1).str[:-1]

market_cap
1.13B
283.56M
763.51M
231.31M
1.3B
```

But I need it as a float, the multiplier based on the `M` or `B` at the end of the `Company Info` column

```
multiplier = {'M': 1e6, 'B': 1e9}
```

Comment: so you want to convert `1.13B` to `1.13e9`? where you got stuck?

Comment: yes pretty much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step by Step

Extract the `market_cap` basically as you had it, except convert to float:

```
df['market_cap'] = df['Company Info'].str.split('$').str.get(1).str[:-1].astype(float)
```

Extract the multiplier using a regex:

```
df['multiplier'] = df['Company Info'].str.extract('\d+\.\d+(\w)')
```

Multiply your market cap by the mapping you provided:

```
df['Market Cap'] = df.market_cap.mul(df['multiplier'].map({'M': 1e6, 'B': 1e9}))

>>> df['Market Cap']
0    6.594000e+07
1    1.990000e+09
2    1.028000e+10
3    1.017000e+10
4    1.990000e+09
Name: Market Cap, dtype: float64
```

## In one Statement

Here is the same as a one liner:

```
df['Market Cap'] = (df['Company Info'].str.split('$')
                    .str.get(1).str[:-1]
                    .astype(float)
                    .mul(df['Company Info']
                         .str.extract('\d+\.\d+(\w)')
                         .map({'M': 1e6, 'B': 1e9})))

>>> df
                                       Company Info    Market Cap
0  Workhorse Group, Inc. (WKHS) Market Cap: $65.94M  6.594000e+07
1            Xencor, Inc. (XNCR) Market Cap: $1.99B  1.990000e+09
2       Zillow Group, Inc. (ZG) Market Cap: $10.28B  1.028000e+10
3        Zillow Group, Inc. (Z) Market Cap: $10.17B  1.017000e+10
4           Zogenix, Inc. (ZGNX) Market Cap: $1.99B  1.990000e+09
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`str.extract`** with **`replace`** and **`prod`**:

```
(df['Company Info'].str.extract(r'\$([\d\.]+)([MB])')
    .replace({'M': 1e6, 'B': 1e9})
    .astype(float).prod(1)
)

0    6.594000e+07
1    1.990000e+09
2    1.028000e+10
3    1.017000e+10
4    1.990000e+09
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```